# In my Blazor server app I read a file on the server line by line but it takes too long. How can I shorten the time?

Tags: c#, file, razor, blazor-server-side, processing-efficiency

In my Blazor server app I want to show the content of a server side file in my razor page. Th file is 5 MB and has appr. 100000 lines. (My app and the file are on the same server, Win2019) I read the file on the server line by line with "File.ReadLines". Reading of the file takes over 20 seconds.I don't know if that is normal for such a file size or amount of lines.

I wanted to know whether I can shorten the reading process, or even if there is a  better way to show the content of the file (read only) on my razor page. The file is a dynamic file, that means its content is changing.

My razor code

```
<table>
    @if(TagService.Error_log_loaded == true)
    {
    @for (int f = 0; f < TagService.Error_log.Count; f++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class=".log_file"><pre class="preformatted">@TagService.Error_log[f]</pre></td>
            </tr>
        }            
    }       
</table>
```

My Blazor code:

```
public async Task Read_Error_Log()
    {
        try
        {
            TagService.Error_log.Clear();
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            var lines = File.ReadLines(CommonClass.error_path, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1254"));
            var line_trimmed = "";

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
              TagService.Error_log.Add(line);
            }
            TagService.Error_log_loaded  = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(CommonClass.error_path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Read_Error_Log() Error " + e + " " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: One efficiency-improvement is to read all lines and assign the whole string array to your error-log. So something like `TagService.Error_log = File.ReadAllLines(...);`. Reading and displaying a file should not take 20s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are doing this but here's a demo which uses async line by line reading to load the data into a `List<string>` and the `Virtualize` component to control the display rows retrieved.  The data file I ran it on contains 1,000,000 lines.  It loads the display immediately with the first set of data, while the service gets the rest of the data in the background.

`FileService` registered as a scoped service.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization;

namespace SO76986556.Data
{
    public class FileService
    {
        private string _fileName = $"{System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{@"\wwwroot\data.txt"}";
        private DateTime _lastWriteTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        private List<string>? _lines;

        public Task FileLoadTask = Task.CompletedTask;

        public async Task ReadFileAsync()
        {
            // Refresh if the data is older than 2 mins
            // probably check the fiel write time or some other method
            // to determine if the log has updated
            if (_lastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2))
            {
                return;
            }

            // Read the data asynchronously into the list
            _lines = new List<string>();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_fileName))
            {
                string? line;

                while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                {
                    _lines.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }

        // The get method for Virtualize
        public async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<string>> GetItemsAsync(ItemsProviderRequest request)
        {
            // if there's no lines the we need to load the data so start, assign the load task 
            // amd wait for a while for the first few hundred lines to be loaded so we have a valid display
            if (_lines == null)
            {
                FileLoadTask = ReadFileAsync();
                await Task.Delay(250);
            }
            if (_lines == null)
                _lines = new List<string>();

            var lines = _lines.Skip(request.StartIndex).Take(request.Count);

            return new ItemsProviderResult<string>(lines, _lines.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

Registered Services:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<FileService>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

And the demo page.

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@inject FileService service;
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@using SO76986556.Data;
@using System.Diagnostics;

@if (_isServerRender)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning">Pre-Rendering</div>
}
else
{
    <Virtualize TItem="string" ItemsProvider="service.GetItemsAsync">
        <ItemContent>
            <div>@context</div>
        </ItemContent>
        <Placeholder>
            <div class="alert alert-warning">The List is currently loading</div>
        </Placeholder>
    </Virtualize>
}

@code {
    private Task? loadingTask;
    private bool _isServerRender;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // check if the page is being pre-rendered
        _isServerRender = !(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is not null && HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted);
    }
}
```

It will need a little tuning and sorting for your situation.

There's a demo Repo here : https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO76986556